# connect and send a message to multiple devices through bluetooth in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I would like to develop an application for sending a message to multiple devices through bluetooth serial communication.

I want to communicate with two paired devices at same time. Is it possible in android ?

```
1.Get the list of paired devices
2.Select a device from paired list
3.Connect to paired device
4.Connect to second paired device.
5.If i can click on one button then it should send two different messages to both connected Bluetooth devices.
```

Can anybody please guide me on this, How can i do this ? Is it possible. I have bluetooth chat application code in this code if i am going to connect with second paired device then first one connection is lost.

Thanks and any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

5.Get connection to another device and so on (one after another).

I am getting paired devices addresses list as follows:

Comment: I think for hire version device you can it using wifi-direct.

Comment: @Sam_k have you google for this ? There are lots of answers.

Comment: @GrIsHu Yes i Googled it but no where i able to find good answer.